# Qt: Applying stylesheet on QScrollArea making horizontal scrollbar disappear but working perfectly for vertical scrollbar

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qscrollarea

I am trying to apply some style-sheet for scrollbars of QScrollArea and my style sheet as follows.

```
QScrollBar:vertical {

  border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;

  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  width: 15px;
  margin: 21px 0 21px 0;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {

  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  min-height: 25px;

}

 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


  QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
      background: none;
  }

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/uparrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/downarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar:horizontal {
  border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0px 21px 0 21px;
 }

 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    min-height: 25px;
 }
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
  border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/leftarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal 
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/rightarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
     background: none;
}
```

This stylesheet perfectly does what it was supposed to for vertical scrollbar but with presence of any single stylesheet related to `QScrollBar:horizontal`, the bar just disappears.

Please can anyone point out my flaw and what should I do?

Notes:
The styleSheet have been applied on QScrollArea object by using `Change styleSheet` option of Qt Designer.

And please kindly acknowledge in case where the horizontal scrollbar shows up with this styleSheet on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are lucky, the same thing just happened to me today.

This really simple, this is because you just copy-past your vertical style for the horizontal and just change the word "vertical" to "horizontal", but actually there is a few more things to change:

- The "width" parameters become "height" in horizontal.
- The "height" parameters become "width".
- "top" and "bottom" become "left" and "right" (that you did).
- Also, if you have asymmetrical margins or such, don't forget to adapt them (you did that too).

This gives the following stylesheet for your particular case:

```
QScrollBar:vertical {

  border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;

  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  width: 15px;
  margin: 21px 0 21px 0;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {

  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  min-height: 25px;

}

 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


  QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
      background: none;
  }

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/uparrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/downarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar:horizontal {
  border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 21px 0 21px;
 }

 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    min-width: 25px;
 }
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
  border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    height: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/leftarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal 
{
  image: url(:/BarIcon/Icons/rightarrow.png);
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
     background: none;
}
```